# Out of memory: Heap Size Error after adding 10KB ImageButtons

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am working in Eclipse on an android app which starts with a splash screen (suspecting Memory Leak here after some research done). The splash screen goes into the main menu consisting of just 7 buttons which lead to some Java Applet. The whole app was working perfectly until I changed the 7 dummy (ImageButton) png images to the finalized 7 png images. These png images have an average of 10KB and don't think they are the cause of the problem (since they're this small), even though this problem started after I changed these png images of the ImageButtons.

Honestly I don't know where to start apart from resizing the images again, cause they are designed a bit large as size in pixels (not memory) to fit different devices. But I think there is another solution to this problem which I as a beginner cannot figure out. I hope someone can help me with this problem :)

Here is the code:

Manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.letsfly.tryp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:debuggable="true" > 
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.letsfly.tryp.MAINACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Testing"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.letsfly.tryp.TESTING" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".trypOne"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.letsfly.tryp.TRYPONE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".trypTwo"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.letsfly.tryp.TRYPTWO" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".trypThree"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.letsfly.tryp.TRYPTHREE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".trypFour"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.letsfly.tryp.TRYPFOUR" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".trypFive"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.letsfly.tryp.TRYPFIVE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Splash XML.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"

    >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="800dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="-180px"
            android:contentDescription="@string/button1"
            android:padding="0px"
            android:src="@drawable/trypsplash" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Splash Java.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Splash extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle waitFiveSeconds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        super.onCreate(waitFiveSeconds);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(5000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }finally{
                    Intent openMenu = new 

Intent("com.letsfly.tryp.MAINACTIVITY");
                        startActivity(openMenu);

                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

MainActivity Java (where the buttons are).

```
package com.letsfly.tryp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageButton button1;
    ImageButton button2;
    ImageButton button3;
    ImageButton button4;
    ImageButton button5;
    ImageButton button6;
    ImageButton button7;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {




        //replace yourActivity.this with your own activity or if you declared a context you can write context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);    

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        button3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        button4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
        button5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
        button6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
        button7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);




        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent goToTrypOne = new Intent("com.letsfly.tryp.TRYPONE");
                startActivity(goToTrypOne);

            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent goToTrypTwo = new Intent("com.letsfly.tryp.TRYPTWO");
                startActivity(goToTrypTwo);


            }
        });
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent goToTrypThree = new Intent("com.letsfly.tryp.TRYPTHREE");
                startActivity(goToTrypThree);

            }
        });
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent goToTrypTwo = new Intent("com.letsfly.tryp.TRYPFOUR");
                startActivity(goToTrypTwo);

            }
        });
        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent goToTrypFive = new Intent("com.letsfly.tryp.TRYPFIVE");
                startActivity(goToTrypFive);

            }
        });
        button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
        button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

MainActivity XML.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button1"
        android:src="@drawable/button1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button2"
        android:src="@drawable/button2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button3"
        android:src="@drawable/button3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button4"
        android:src="@drawable/button4"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/button5"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button6"
        android:src="@drawable/button6"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button7"
        android:src="@drawable/button7"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please add a `logcat` error.

Comment: The size of an image file is not relevant since PNG and JPG apply image compression techniques to make the image data smaller than it really is. When you render these images or apply them to `ImageButton`views images are decoded and take up more memory than the file size indicates. If your PNG is for example 1024x1024 with all red color, the file can be very small, but the decoded bitmap in memory will be `1024 * 1024 * bytes_per_pixel` big.

Comment: Thanks so much for this information it really really explains and helps a lot and my situation makes much more sense. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Being large in pixels actually is the issue, as Android will need to inflate the compressed pngs into uncompressed bitmaps in memory to display them.

Instead of making large pngs that scale down to accomodate different size/density devices, instead use drawable folders with different qualifiers:

```
Images for mdpi devices: /res/drawable-mdpi
Images for hdpi devices: /res/drawable-hdpi
Images for xhdpi devices: /res/drawable-xhdpi
Images for xxhdpi devices: /res/drawable-xxhdpi
```

When you request an image (say, R.drawable.myImage), it will look for a myImage file in the folder that has the density qualifier that best matches the device. This lets you automatically make sure that small density devices are using images with a smaller memory footprint.

More information here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is my first mobile app so am quite new and slow to understand, so excuse me. 

So should I put the same png in the different folders, or scale them accordingly?

Also in my code I use the id and call it with `id` like so:

`button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);`

does this makes a difference since the image is functioning as a button not just an image? 

Would changing that code interfere with the `OnClickListener()` which is controlled by the button1, starting like this..

`button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`

Comment: You should scale them accordingly for each folder - i.e. mdpi should have smaller images than hdpi. Wherever you refer to the drawable (doesn't have to be an `ImageView`), Android will try to find the best fitting drawable for the device, according to the drawable folder qualifiers. Your click listeners are unrelated to this, and should not have any effect.