# Android OutOfMemoryError on 5k bitmap

Tags: android

I do

```
myImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mydrawable);
```

and I get an `OutOfMemoryError`. But the resource is only 5kb !!! I had various stack trace, sometimes not saying anything, sometimes saying I was using around 5Mb and sometimes 7Mb.

This is on the Galaxy S4. On other devices I don't get the error. Is the GC known for being slow to trigger on certain devices ? Any other idea ?

Comment: Is it a `PNG`? Are you sure *this* is the resource throwing the `OOM`?

Comment: @nKn it is a `PNG`, and it is when I set it that the error is thrown, sure about that

Comment: Would it be possible to convert it to another format such as `JPG`, or you need it to be a `PNG`? One thing is how long is the file on the disk, but another one very different is how much data it takes to the `Bitmap` to represent it, and that's even worse with `PNG`.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636510/android-out-of-memory-regarding-png-image

Comment: then set it through XML..my guess is it is not with the image..

Comment: @nKn the image has some transparent parts unfortunately. But it is just 80x80 pixels

Comment: @GVSharma there is a `if` somewhere, I can't do that by xml. Agreed there can be something else fishy, any idea how to inspect that ?

Comment: post the log message.....

Comment: This could help too, seems that `PNG` get expanded pretty much in memory and cause an `OOM` even with small images: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262919/out-of-memory-heap-size-error-after-adding-10kb-imagebuttons

Comment: is it all 80x80 or is it just the opaque part, and the transparent one is bigger?

Comment: "But the resource is only 5kb !" -- so? If a bridge has a weight limit of 1000kg, and you put 950kg on it, then add 100kg more, and the bridge collapses, you cannot complain that "but the additional weight was only 100kg!". Your problem probably has little to do with this particular resource and more to do with your heap usage overall. Use MAT to determine what is going on with your application's heap.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your image in a `/drawable-nodpi` folder instead of `/drawable`

Comment: what is `nodpi` for ?

Comment: "/drawable" generic folder is considered by the system like "/drawable/mdpi", so when you run the app with hdpi device or more the images are resized, and become too big.

Comment: If that doesn't solve your problem, you might have to scale your image down. You can do so using `inSampleSize` of bitmap factory. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html